# How to make recyclerview autoscroll horizontally.?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have put one recycler view in my project. I want that it will be auto-scroll horizontally. For achieving this I have made one custom class. but I also want that existing functions which I put on my recycler view will also remain.

CustomLinearLayoutManager:

```
public class CustomLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    public CustomLinearLayoutManager (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
        final LinearSmoothScroller linearSmoothScroller =
                new LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext()) {
                    private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 200f;

                    @Override
                    public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
                        return CustomLinearLayoutManager.this
                                .computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel
                            (DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                        return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
                    }
                };
        linearSmoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroll(linearSmoothScroller);
    }
}
```

Home Class

```
private RecyclerView recyclerViewHeaderSlider;
    private HeaderSliderAdapter headerSliderAdapter;
    private List<Banner> banners;

banners = new ArrayList<>();
        headerSliderAdapter = new HeaderSliderAdapter(getActivity(), banners);

recyclerViewHeaderSlider = view.findViewById(R.id.bannerSlider);
        SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewHeaderSlider);
        recyclerViewHeaderSlider.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewHeaderSlider.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        headerSliderAdapter.setOnClick(this);
        recyclerViewHeaderSlider.setAdapter(headerSliderAdapter);
```

I want to implement my custom linear layout manager with Home class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Runnable to autoscroll Horizontal RV

```
public void autoScroll(){
    speedScroll = 0;
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        int count = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(count == tickerAdapter.getItemCount())
                count = 0;
            else {
                if(count < tickerAdapter.getItemCount()){
                    rvTicker.smoothScrollToPosition(++count);
                    handler.postDelayed(this,speedScroll);
                }else {
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,speedScroll);
}
```